# Mysql count column issue

Tags: php, mysql, count

I can't figure-it out how to count all these dancers columns and echo with total of all dancers

```
id | dancer1 | dancer2 | dancer3 | dancer4, and so on..
---------------------------------------
1     alex     michael    dalm      name
2     clare    rose       test
```

I have this for the start but is not working:

```
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM table");

$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter); 
$dancers = $num["id"];

echo "Total dancers: $dancers";
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the table structure a bit more? What is the id 1 and 2 associate to? Their forename/surname? If so you need to re-organise the table structure. count(*) will count the number of rows. What number are you expecting and receiving?

Comment: If you have numbered columns like this, it's generally a good indication that you need to properly normalise your database structure

Comment: how many dancer you have for each compitition????

Comment: from 1 to 24 dancers  for each user that is signed for competition

Comment: is there any blank fields here within these 24 fields???

Comment: Yes , bcz if user have only 6 dancers or 1 or 2 , all remaining dancers fields will be blank

Comment: @Fido, Check out my answer.

Comment: okay sorry i was afk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$dancers = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($counter)){
    for($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++){
        $dan_id = 'dancer'.$i;
        if($rows[$dan_id] != "" || $rows[$dan_id] != null )
            $dancers++;
    }   
}
echo "Total dancers:". $dancers;
```

> **Note:** Never design your database table like this.

Comment: Frayne Konok, can u show me how to count individualy based on table ids? To list each user with number of dancers added?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually save your dancers in a different (easier) way... For examle:

ID     NAME   SURNAME     PHONE    ....

1      Anna   Brickstone   0975     ...

2      Jef     Damen       0754     ...

**That way you could use the following code to count tables:**

```
$dancersCount="0";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dancers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dancersCount++;
}
} else {
   echo "No dancers..";
}

echo"$dancersCount";
```

The counter will count +1 each time it finds a row (dancer)

**If you really want to do it that way...**

Then I don't really think there's an easy way to fix this... You will probably need to check how many columns you have in your database but that's not something i can help you with...

Comment: it will show only 2. But the OP want to count the dancers.

Comment: Ow.. Didn't get that so well... I'll see what i can do then... I'll change my answer in a sec...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, essentially this is just a very convoluted `SELECT COUNT(*) ... ` ?

Comment: Yeah... This is the way I usually do things instead of using the count, but if this is a beginner I think he will be able to do more after the counting using this (Like displaying names while he counts)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your table structure:

```
id | dancerNumber  | name
1      1             alex
2      1             clare
3      2             michael
4      2             rose
5      3             dalm
6      3             test
7      4             name
8      4             dana
```

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM table` will return 8 dancers. If this is what you were looking for?

if you want to keep your structure then you need to do the following sql query

```
SELECT   dancer1,
         dancer2,
         dancer3,
         (CASE WHEN (dancer1 <> "" AND dancer1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN (dancer2 <> "" AND dancer2 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
         CASE WHEN (dancer3 <> "" AND dancer3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNTER
FROM     table
```

This will count all the non empty and non null columns and add a counter at the end of the table. this counter will then contain the number of dancers with your structure.

**Full answer with your php code**

```
$query = 'SELECT (CASE WHEN (dancer1 <> "" AND dancer1 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                 CASE WHEN (dancer2 <> "" AND dancer2 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                 CASE WHEN (dancer3 <> "" AND dancer3 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNTER 
FROM table'

$counter = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter); 
$dancers = $num["COUNTER"];

echo "Total dancers: $dancers";
```

Comment: Each user has to submit a number of dancers for a dance competition, and in the table i have: "id", "username", "clubname", "crew",  "dancer1", "dancer2", etc.."dancer24" and so on.. and i want to calculate each user dancer fields and shows me an total number of all dancers from the table

Comment: @Fido I have added a new sql command to live with your structure ofcourse you need to fill in the rest to make it up to 24 dancers. Please in the future look at changing your table structure.

Comment: added in a not null argument as well